# How to know which certificate has been used to code sign an iPhone build based on the app bundle alone?

Tags: iphone

I am building my app for adhoc distribution and appstore distribution.  When I go into the Xcode code signing settings, there is only two listings in there: Developer:<...> and Distribution: <...>

I know I have three certificates in the system, one for developer, one for adhoc and one for appstore distribution.  How can I tell which certificate a particular app bundle has been code signed with just to make sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XCode's Organizer you have a list of Provisioning Profiles. Each provisioning profile has an associated profile identifier, which looks something like a GUID. When you build your app and XCode signs it you'll see that profile identifier displayed in the signing step: something like:

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/01234567-0123-0123-0123-012345678901.mobileprovision" -o ~/.../MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision
```

(The line in the Build Results window will start with "`ProcessingProductPackaging`"...